# get_relation function in dbt not working as expected

Tags: google-bigquery, dbt

I have a model in dbt that is built on source data. The source data is such that it is sometimes available and sometimes not, so I'm trying to use the adapter.get_relations() function to check if the source table exists and only query the table if it exists. However, even after adding this logic, when dbt runs and the source table isn't there, the error `400 GET <bigquery_source_table_link> does not match any table` is thrown.

The code being used:

```
{%- set source_relation = adapter.get_relation(
            database=source('analytics', 'events_intraday_*').database,
            schema=source('analytics', 'events_intraday_*').schema,
            identifier=source('analytics', 'events_intraday_*').name,
        )  -%}

{% set table_exists = source_relation is not none %}

        {% if table_exists %}

            select
                user_pseudo_id,
                event_timestamp,
                event_name,
                event_params
            from {{ source('analytics', 'events_intraday_*') }}

        {% else %}

            select
                cast(null as string) as user_pseudo_id,
                cast(null as int) as event_timestamp,
                cast(null as string) as event_name,
                null as event_params

        {% endif %}
```

Answer (score 0):

Per the [dbt documentation](https://docs.getdbt.com/reference/resource-properties/identifier#reference-sharded-tables-as-a-source-in-bigquery), i think you need to use an `identifier` for sharded tables.

Define your source with an identifier:

```
sources:
  - name: events
    tables:
      - name: events_intraday
        identifier: "events_intraday_*"
```

Then use it in a downstream source:

```
{{ source('events', 'events_intraday') }}
```